# Iterating and comparing list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists in Python:

```
checkNameArr = [['551002', 'Derek Jones'], 
                ['940874', 'Hugh Lunny'], 
                ['104741', 'Richard Plaith'], 
                ['310125', 'Aideen Toner'], 
                ['305795', 'Vikki Trench'], 
                ['218714', 'Paul Cutland'], 
                ['401741', 'Russell Smith'], 
                ['223996', 'Chloe Green'], 
                ['845216', 'Simon Fallon'], 
                ['402258', 'Chris Worth']]

queryNameArr = [['551002', 'Derek Jones'], 
                ['940874', 'Hugh Lunny'], 
                ['823085', 'Brian Deans'], 
                ['310125', 'Aideen Toner'], 
                ['571454', 'Pam Scales'], 
                ['967825', 'Una Lingus'], 
                ['401741', 'Russell Smith'], 
                ['682301', 'Hannah Jacobs'], 
                ['914774', 'Elaine Glass'], 
                ['402258', 'Chris Worth']]
```

And I would like to compare the number value in each list. I know that I would need to iterate through one list to compare it to the first value of the next list, if a match is found, store it in a found list. If it isn't found, store that value in a not found list. I am trying to do this in the smallest amount of code possible but the logistics of this are confusing me.

What would be a nice clean solution?

Comment: So you prefer less code than performance?

Comment: Do you only need the elements contained in both? And do you need the elements in a specific order?

Comment: Why people always want to write "smallest amount of code"? Your concern should be writing *clear* and *readable* code, not small.

Comment: I apologise for the ambiguity of this. What I mean is, that I am writing more code than I should to find a solution to this. I end up stripping the first element of each list into 2 new lists and then comparing those and creating lists to store the data. It becomes confusing and very hard to read in the end. I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: i would like to compare the lists to see if any of the elements match within the other list. If they do, have a new list with only matched elements and a list with unmatched elements

Comment: So what output do you want? :)

Comment: Is the same number always going to do with the same name, even across lists?

Comment: My apologies again! Ok, so I would like to compare the queryNameArr to the checkNameArr and if an element in the list matches, store it in a matchingArr list, if not then store the element in a notMatchingArr list

Comment: @IainBlackwood, sorry if I'm being terse. I understand what you're saying there, but I'm asking you to post the exact output you want in the question. That way it's easier for everyone to understand, and we reduce the possibility of misunderstanding :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert the list in which you want to check to `set` by converting each inner element to tuple and then iterate over the other list and check if its element (converted to tuple) exists in the set, if so add it to found list, else add it to notfound list.

Example -

```
checkNameSet = set(map(tuple, checkNameArr))
found = []
notfound = []
for i in queryNameArr:
    if tuple(i) in checkNameSet:
        found.append(i)
    else:
        notfound.append(i)
```

Demo -

```
>>> checkNameArr = [['551002', 'Derek Jones'],
...                 ['940874', 'Hugh Lunny'],
...                 ['104741', 'Richard Plaith'],
...                 ['310125', 'Aideen Toner'],
...                 ['305795', 'Vikki Trench'],
...                 ['218714', 'Paul Cutland'],
...                 ['401741', 'Russell Smith'],
...                 ['223996', 'Chloe Green'],
...                 ['845216', 'Simon Fallon'],
...                 ['402258', 'Chris Worth']]
>>>
>>> queryNameArr = [['551002', 'Derek Jones'],
...                 ['940874', 'Hugh Lunny'],
...                 ['823085', 'Brian Deans'],
...                 ['310125', 'Aideen Toner'],
...                 ['571454', 'Pam Scales'],
...                 ['967825', 'Una Lingus'],
...                 ['401741', 'Russell Smith'],
...                 ['682301', 'Hannah Jacobs'],
...                 ['914774', 'Elaine Glass'],
...                 ['402258', 'Chris Worth']]
>>>
... checkNameSet = set(map(tuple, checkNameArr))
>>> found = []
>>> notfound = []
>>> for i in queryNameArr:
...     if tuple(i) in checkNameSet:
...             found.append(i)
...     else:
...             notfound.append(i)
...
>>> found
[['551002', 'Derek Jones'], ['940874', 'Hugh Lunny'], ['310125', 'Aideen Toner'], ['401741', 'Russell Smith'], ['402258', 'Chris Worth']]
>>> notfound
[['823085', 'Brian Deans'], ['571454', 'Pam Scales'], ['967825', 'Una Lingus'], ['682301', 'Hannah Jacobs'], ['914774', 'Elaine Glass']]
```

---

If you only want to compare using one element or a subset of elements of the inner list, instead of storing the complete tuple of inner list in the set, we can use `operator.itemgetter()` to get just the element to compare and store that alone.

And then compare using that alone , Code -

```
import operator
checkNameSet = set(map(operator.itemgetter(0), checkNameArr))
found = []
notfound = []
for i in queryNameArr:
    if i[0] in checkNameSet:
        found.append(i)
    else:
        notfound.append(i)
```

Example/Demo for this -

```
>>> checkNameArr = [['551002', 'Derek Jones'],
...                 ['940874', 'Hugh Lunny'],
...                 ['104741', 'Richard Plaith'],
...                 ['310125', 'Aideen Toner'],
...                 ['305795', 'Vikki Trench'],
...                 ['218714', 'Paul Cutland'],
...                 ['401741', 'Russell Smith'],
...                 ['223996', 'Chloe Green'],
...                 ['845216', 'Simon Fallon'],
...                 ['402258', 'Chris Worth']]
>>>
>>> queryNameArr = [['551002', 'Derek Jones'],
...                 ['940874', 'Hugh Lunny'],
...                 ['823085', 'Brian Deans'],
...                 ['310125', 'Aideen Toner'],
...                 ['571454', 'Pam Scales'],
...                 ['967825', 'Una Lingus'],
...                 ['401741', 'Russell Smith'],
...                 ['682301', 'Hannah Jacobs'],
...                 ['914774', 'Elaine Glass'],
...                 ['402258', 'Chris Worth']]
>>>
... checkNameSet = set(map(operator.itemgetter(0), checkNameArr))
>>> found = []
>>> notfound = []
>>> for i in queryNameArr:
...     if i[0] in checkNameSet:
...             found.append(i)
...     else:
...             notfound.append(i)
...
>>> found
[['551002', 'Derek Jones'], ['940874', 'Hugh Lunny'], ['310125', 'Aideen Toner'], ['401741', 'Russell Smith'], ['402258', 'Chris Worth']]
>>> notfound
[['823085', 'Brian Deans'], ['571454', 'Pam Scales'], ['967825', 'Una Lingus'], ['682301', 'Hannah Jacobs'], ['914774', 'Elaine Glass']]
```

Comment: I selected this as the answer because you showed me how to work with just the 1st element within the list of lists (the numeric value)

Answer (score 1):

```
matchingArr = [item for item in queryNameArr if item in checkNameArr]
notMatchingArr = [item for item in queryNameArr if not item in checkNameArr]
```

Result:

```
[['551002', 'Derek Jones'],
 ['940874', 'Hugh Lunny'],
 ['310125', 'Aideen Toner'],
 ['401741', 'Russell Smith'],
 ['402258', 'Chris Worth']]

[['823085', 'Brian Deans'],
 ['571454', 'Pam Scales'],
 ['967825', 'Una Lingus'],
 ['682301', 'Hannah Jacobs'],
 ['914774', 'Elaine Glass']]
```

---

An alternative based on sets:

```
matchingArr = map(list, set(map(tuple, queryNameArr)).intersection(set(map(tuple, checkNameArr))))
notMatchingArr = map(list, set(map(tuple, queryNameArr)).difference(set(map(tuple, checkNameArr))))
```

The conversion from `list` to `tuple` and vice versa is somewhat annoying... (but needed, because sets can't work on lists).

Comment: I think checkNameArr and queryNameArr should be swapped in both. Otherwise, you beat me to it :).

Comment: @Cyphase: Oh, I see. Ok, I switched the two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
# first, let’s create a set of the check list to quickly check for membership
checkNameSet = set(tuple(x) for x in checkNameArr)

# create lists for matched, and unmatched names
matched = []
unmatched = []

# iterate the query names
for query in queryNameArr:
    # if the query name is in the check set, add it to matched, otherwise unmatched
    if tuple(query) in checkNameSet:
        matched.append(query)
    else:
        unmatched.append(query)
```

```
>>> matched
[['551002', 'Derek Jones'], ['940874', 'Hugh Lunny'], ['310125', 'Aideen Toner'], ['401741', 'Russell Smith'], ['402258', 'Chris Worth']]
>>> unmatched
[['823085', 'Brian Deans'], ['571454', 'Pam Scales'], ['967825', 'Una Lingus'], ['682301', 'Hannah Jacobs'], ['914774', 'Elaine Glass']]
```